# Retrieving data from Stored Procedure which is not in a ROW [ASP.NET C#]

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

just wondering if how can we retrieve a data from stored procedure, who's return value is not in a row. I've run the stored procedure and it doesn't return any rows but return some data >.< just like this photo. could anyone know how to retrieve return value @rtncode in .NET?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes sir, I think so, since the declaration in stored procedure of @rtncode is int OUTPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code on using an OUTPUT parameter and ADO.NET

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@yourParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        command.CommandText = "YOUR_STORED_PROCEDURE";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return parameter.Value;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically such Stored Procedures are invoked by way of the [**ExecuteNonQuery**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method of an SqlCommand (from System.Data.SqlClient).

Both output parameters or the return value are populated by ExecuteNonQuery.